# Getting "plugin with id'com.google.gms.google-services' not found." error in android studio

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

In`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'`
no need to add plugins for google services. My project was working fine.
when i update it to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

i got `duplicate resource` error.
then i add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in build.gradle file.
now i getting

```
Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
```

what should i do?

Comment: add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:***`??

Comment: after adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` i am getting `Error: Duplicate resources` error again.

Comment: I'm getting the duplicate resources error as well.  Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Check your build.gradle(app) and build.gradle(project) and if you can't see the issue, post both here.